# Get the position of an input on click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to know the position of input box using `ng-click`. Following is the controller code in which I am consoling the event `pageX` and `clientX` but rather than giving the position for input element they are giving the values according to mouse click. Let me know if any property available to extract this info. (btw I am not looking for the directive way)

**Controller Code** -

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.clicked = function(e) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.pageX);
    console.log(e.clientX);
  };
})
```

**HTML Code -**

```
<input type="text" ng-click="clicked($event)" />
```

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/f9HoVeSUwKUe9QSOB2jC?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use **[`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)** over `e.target`

**Event.target**: *A reference to the object that dispatched the event.*

*The `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.*

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clicked = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getBoundingClientRect());
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-click="clicked($event)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple! :)

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.clicked = function(e) {
    var el = e.currentTarget;
    var place = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(place);
    console.log('X coordinate - '+place.x);
    console.log('Y coordinate - '+place.y);
  };
})
```

Comment: I get place.x undefined... :O